# How to list the VIEWs (not cameras) in Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge, viewer

we have been successfully listing the available cameras on our view by using this piece of code:

```
NOP_VIEWER.model.getData().cameras
```

This automatically lists all cameras loaded with the model. However we noticed some models only have 1 camera, even though we see more **views**:

[Model listing 7 views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkeMc.jpg)

The question is: how can we get a list of those views (not the cameras)?

Notes: this model was created in 3DS Max and then exported to SVF.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the input file format, the [Model Derivative](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/) service can export many different "viewables" as we call them. For example, for a single Revit document, the service can generate a viewable for every 3D view, and a viewable for every 2D sheet. The same probably applies to 3dsMax files - individual views are exported as separate "viewables". You can see the list of all the viewables using the Model Derivative APIs such as:

- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-GET/, or
- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/

Comment: Hi Petr, is it possible to use the results from the Model Derivative APIs to create cameras on Forge Viewer? The idea is to mimic the same behavior as we see when we "share" a model from 3DSMax and it generates a link with a viewer inside (that's the source of the image I attached to the question)

Comment: Try looking at the manifest of your 3ds Max design in Forge (using [this endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/)). It might include the camera info for the different "viewables".

Comment: I was not able to run the Model Derivative API using the URN we currently have (it keeps giving BadRequest). Please note that we did not translate the model using the Model Derivative API in the first place, we exported to SVF using 3DMax. Do you know if it should work in this case? NOTE: it does work when we run the Model Derivative API using the URN of another model translated using the Model Derivative API.

Comment: Ah ok, in that case this might be some specific behavior of the 3dsMax-to-SVF extraction. I'm not familiar with that one unfortunately.